# Applying progress bar to the winform on button click

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

Can anyone guide me to how can I apply a distinct progress bar in my winform on the click of a button

Comment: what's "distinct progress bar"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProgressBar p = new ProgressBar();
    p.Location = new Point(10, 10);
    p.Size = new Size(100, 30);
    this.Controls.Add(p);
}
```